# How to get the role from the current user?

Tags: java, kotlin, keycloak, vert.x

I am trying to implement **AuthN/AuthZ with JWT** as the following:

```
class MainVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {

  private suspend fun initConfig(): JsonObject {
    val yamlConfigOpts = ConfigStoreOptions()
      .setFormat("yaml")
      .setType("file")
      .setConfig(JsonObject().put("path", "config.yaml"))

    val configRetrieverOpts = ConfigRetrieverOptions()
      .addStore(yamlConfigOpts)

    val configRetriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, configRetrieverOpts)

    return configRetriever.config.await()
  }


  private suspend fun createJwtAuth(client: WebClient, config: JsonObject): JWTAuth? {

    val issuer = config.getJsonObject("jwt").getString("issuer")

    // derive JWKS uri from Keycloak issuer URI
    val jwksUri = URI.create("${issuer}/protocol/openid-connect/certs")

    // The exception will be caught above
    val res = client.get(jwksUri.host, jwksUri.path).send().await()

    return res.bodyAsJsonObject()?.let {
      val keys = it.getJsonArray("keys")

      val jwtOpt = JWTOptions()
      jwtOpt.issuer = issuer


      // configure JWTAuth
      val jwtAuthOptions = JWTAuthOptions()

      jwtAuthOptions.jwks = (keys.list as List<Map<String, *>>)
        .map { json -> JsonObject(json) }
        .map { json -> json.put("permissionsClaimKey", "realm_access/roles") }
      jwtAuthOptions.jwtOptions = jwtOpt



      JWTAuth.create(vertx, jwtAuthOptions)
    } ?: throw AuthenticationException("Can not receive the token")

  }

  private fun createRoutes(router: Router, jwtAuth: JWTAuth): Unit {

    router.route("/api/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwtAuth))

    router.route("/api/greet").handler {

      val token = it.request().getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).substring("Bearer ".length)

      jwtAuth.authenticate(JsonObject().put("jwt", token))
        .onSuccess { user ->
          val res = it.response()
          res.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")

          // Write to the response and end it
          res.end("I am interests path")
        }
        .onFailure { err -> it.response().setStatusCode(403).end(err.message) }


    }

  }


  private suspend fun server(router: Router): HttpServer {
    val server = vertx.createHttpServer()

    return server.requestHandler(router)
      .listen(8080)
      .onSuccess {
        println("HTTP server started on port ${it.actualPort()}")
      }
      .onFailure {
        println("Failed to start the server. Reason ${it.message}")
      }
      .await()
  }


  override suspend fun start() {

    val config = initConfig()
    val webClient = WebClient.create(vertx)
    val router = Router.router(vertx)

    createJwtAuth(webClient, config)?.let {
      createRoutes(router, it)
      server(router)

    }
  }
}
```

In the `/api/greet` route handler, I would like to read out the claims of the user, for instance the role or name. But unfortunately, this is all what I've got:

[image]

The question is, how to read claims from the user?

I am using Keycloak as Identity Provider and Vertx version `4.0.0.CR1`.

**UPDATE**

I have changed to [OAuth2 auth provider](https://vertx-web-site.github.io/docs/vertx-auth-oauth2/java/) and adjusted the code as follows:

```
class MainVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {

  private suspend fun createJwtAuth(): OAuth2Auth =

    KeycloakAuth.discover(
      vertx,
      OAuth2Options()
        .setFlow(OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE)
        .setClientID("svc")
        .setClientSecret("secret")
        .setSite("https://oic.example.io/auth/realms/vertx")
    ).await()


  private fun createRoutes(router: Router, auth: OAuth2Auth): Unit {

    val oauth2 = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(vertx, auth)

    router.route("/api/*").handler(oauth2)

    router.route("/api/greet").handler {

      println(it.user().principal().getString("preferred_username"))

      val res = it.response()
      res.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")

      // Write to the response and end it
      res.end("I am interests path")


    }

  }


  private suspend fun server(router: Router): HttpServer {
    val server = vertx.createHttpServer()

    return server.requestHandler(router)
      .listen(8080)
      .onSuccess {
        println("HTTP server started on port ${it.actualPort()}")
      }
      .onFailure {
        println("Failed to start the server. Reason ${it.message}")
      }
      .await()
  }


  override suspend fun start() {

    val router = Router.router(vertx)


    createRoutes(router, createJwtAuth())
    server(router)

  }

}
```

The line

```
println(it.user().principal().getString("preferred_username"))
```

prints `null` instead username. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to see what's inside your token? I mean have you copied the value of "access_token" and check it in https://jwt.io/ to see if the roles or other claims you want. already exists and have proper value?

Comment: Inside the `access_token`, I can see all the relevant information `realm_access` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using the current latest releases, let me explain a bit the changes in the new API. In 4.0.0 we're split `authn` and `authz` so in your example you already perform `authn` correctly and get a `User` object instance.

Now you want to extract permissions, as you're doing `JWTAuth` you're taking the "low" level path, while if you'd be using `OAuth2Auth` some things would be not necessary (such as loading of keys, etc...).

Now that you have a user object you need to have a `authz` extraction object. For this I'll be exemplifying with the java API but in Kotlin it should be quite similar:

```
// First create a JWTAuthorization object
JWTAuthorization.create("realm_access/roles")
  .getAuthorizations(user)
  .onSuccess(success -> {
    // The authorizations have been successfully extracted from the user
    // Now you can perform any kind of checks

    if (PermissionBasedAuthorization.create("write").match(user)) {
      // ... User is allowed to write...
    }
  });
```

So, the permissions are extracted from the `attributes` under the `claimKey` you pass to the extractor. In a nutshell, `attributes` are generated and or decoded/validated data that was produced by the framework, while `principal` is the source data that was provided to create the user. The distinction is important as now the user object can be used both for server validation and client requests.

Also this means that keeping the source untouched, there are no risks that decoding would overwrite important data such as expiration dates and the such.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, I should use https://vertx-web-site.github.io/docs/vertx-auth-oauth2/java/ right?

Comment: What I would like to do is, to protect my api service with Keycloak. I am quite confuse.